# In responsive view, how to make profile picture as portrait which is taken at landscape mode?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, landscape-portrait

In responsive site, we taken profile picture in mobile camera in landscape view and upload the files in that site. but it does not set in portrait view in the profile image box. Its turn -90deg and show in landscape view.

Is there any possibility to set the image in portrait view. please give your suggestion. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/f4fhn0wn/1/

```
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;

    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Adam. How to find that image in landscape view or portrait. view. and also when user upload image using camera that time we find landscape or portrait after only change the rotation. incase user upload the image in portrait mode mean that time image turn. so i need any other suggestion please. and once again i like to say thanks.